# How to use Lwt with Labltk?

Tags: ocaml, tk-toolkit, ocaml-lwt

How to write a program using Lwt and interacting with a Tk interface.  I tried to run the Tk main thread in a Lwt preemptive thread with

```
let () =
  Lwt.async(Lwt_preemptive.detach Tkthread.thread_main);
  Lwt_main.run(main Tkthread.top)
```

where `main` constructs the interface and runs a thread updating it. This ends up in the programming crashing with a fatal error (unable to create widget) and after that, a core dump.

What is the correct way to use Lwt and Labltk together?

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to use LablTk with Lwt, but `tkThread.mli` clearly says:

> Jobs are needed for Windows, as you cannot do GUI work from
>      another thread. This is apparently true on OSX/Aqua too.
>      And even using X11 some calls need to come from the main thread.
>      The basic idea is to either use async (if you don't need a result)
>      or sync whenever you call a Tk related function from another thread
>      (for instance with the threaded toplevel).
>      With sync, beware of deadlocks!

Therefore I propose to wrap your calls of LablTk with `TkThread.sync`.

You should also ask the question at caml-list.  Probably someone there have tried this before.